# Gmail Script - label.getUnreadCount() issue

Tags: google-apps-script, count, gmail, label

Google Apps Script

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label

```
getUnreadCount()

// log the number of unread threads labeled with MyLabel
   var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
   Logger.log(label.getUnreadCount());

Gets the number of unread threads tagged with this label.
```

When i tried the sample code provided, it return a different unread value.

From the email, it shows 17 unread but the log file shows 12.

Any ideas?

Comment: Played around the method and tested with couple of labels and different scenarios. The method is returning correct results. Make sure you are running the script and authenticating with the same email that you are checking the label from.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this script thoroughly and found that although, it gets a count of the emails marked with the label from the Inbox, however, it will not count the emails marked which are in maybe some other folder but have the same label. So if you have 17 unread emails with a label (assuming it like your question) "MyLabel", then my guess is 12 of those are in the Inbox but 5 of those have skipped/been moved from the Inbox and hence are not being counted by the function.

However, one of the work-arounds is to use:

`var threads = label.getThreads();`

and move add of all of these to Inbox while keeping these files marked with your label. Now, if you count, your function should return 17. But ideally you shouldn't have to do that, so I would suggest that you also file it as a defect [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and make use of the work-around in the meanwhile.